# Passing value from controller to view spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am very new to spring. From my controller I got a list output.

`[[Article@42e72033 id = 1, title = 'Hello', description = 'Description', author = 'eeee'], [Article@7702e860 id = 2, title = 'Hello', description = 'Description', author = 'eeee'], [Article@3c2731ff id = 3, title = 'Hello', description = 'Description', author = 'eeee'], [Article@157e7973 id = 4, title = 'qqqq', description = 'qqqqq', author = 'qqqqq']]`

I want to use the title,description and author in my articles/view.html which currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="~{fragments/layout :: layout (~{::body},'owners')}">

<body>


<table id="vets" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Title</th>

        <th>Description</th>
        <th style="width: 120px">Author</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How to get the values from the list and display in the body section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make sure the controller that is rendering the view is passing the List attribute to the model.  If the list attribute you are providing is called articles your body tag should have an iterator configured for the list, something like:

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="article : ${articles}">
<td th:text="${article.title}"><td>
<td th:text="${article.description}"><td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

mkez00's answer (+1) will solve your problem. Still I would like to show you the same thing without any template engine (Thymeleaf) as you said you are very new to Spring.

Few things you need to know about first:

- [`JSP` (JavaServer Pages)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagy.html)
- [`JSTL` (JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html)
- [`EL` (Expression Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html)

[These are from JavaEE 5 tutorial but still relevant. Do your own research from various available resources!]

Now for your problem, if you have put a `List` of your `Article` objects in model in your controller like this:

```
model.put("articles", yourListOfArticles);
```

in view (a `JSP` here) you can do the following to show the table you want:

***articles.jsp***

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="vets" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 150px;">Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th style="width: 120px">Author</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${articles}" var="article">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${article.title}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${article.description}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${article.author}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```